# How to change the title text color of UI Button?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I tried changing the colors of the text for a button, but it's still staying white. Please help me.

```
isbeauty = UIButton()
isbeauty.setTitle("Buy", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
isbeauty.titleLabel?.textColor = UIColorFromRGB("F21B3F")
isbeauty.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin" , size: 25)
isbeauty.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
isbeauty.layer.cornerRadius = 5
isbeauty.layer.borderWidth = 1
isbeauty.layer.borderColor = UIColorFromRGB("F21B3F").CGColor
isbeauty.frame = CGRectMake(300, 134, 55, 26)
isbeauty.addTarget(self,action: "first:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
self.view.addSubview(isbeauty)
```

Comment: Avoid accessing directly to `titleLabel` with a equivalent with `forState:` is available. Instead use `setTitleColor(_:forState:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example - white title text, gray when highlighted (tap is down):

```
isbeauty.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
isbeauty.setTitleColor(.gray, for: .highlighted)
```